# Is there a direct-method video series for Hebrew?

Tags: resource-request, hebrew, direct-method

I found [this video series](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=IZPzSIemRz4) a while ago that teaches Esperanto by only speaking Esperanto. It starts with simple phrases and then builds up from there.

Does something like this exist for Hebrew? I searched for it without success but I suppose someone may have captioned it in a language other than English, in which case it wouldn't come up in my search results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Biblical Hebrew, apparently in a sephardic accent, Aleph with Beth is what you want:

https://www.youtube.com/@AlephwithBeth

or at:

https://freehebrew.online/

you can get a bittorrent file for the first seventy or so lessons.

I've just done the first fifty lessons (about a hundred or so videos, watch one per day and then watch yesterday's again, so maybe an hour a day) and it's wonderful.

The only reason I did it is because it seems to be considered in the Latin and ancient Greek communities to be the ideal to which ancient language teaching should aspire, and I wanted to find out what that was like.

It's constantly interesting and fun, I've almost never had to use the companion grammar they provide, and it clearly works. I can usually understand immediately when Beth reads a new bit of the Bible out loud.

No effort involved. Just watch the videos.

She's even getting me interested in the actual Bible stories.

I can hardly read or write it though, it's all going in aurally and writing hasn't been necessary. An amazing experience.

I really can't recommend it highly enough.

Answer (score 1):

If for free, I would recommend Dr. Bill Barrick's series which is available on YouTube.  Here is a link to the first in the series:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qvh8yziVsCE  However, I cannot recommend it because you cannot get the book or study materials that goes with the series.

I far prefer Dr. Mile's VanPelt's "Basics for Biblical Hebrew" series.  He has the first 3 chapters available for free on YouTube:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIfLf_ffDyw

The reason I recommend Basics for Biblical Hebrew is that it has every resource that a self-learner would want.  Videos, flashcards, cheat sheets, computer flashcards, etc.  My copy of "Biblical Hebrew A Compact Guide" is taped together and totally shot because I use it so much.

Once you get the reading/writing down:   This series is probably what you want:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xr9amXnFRrs

Comment: Thanks for a thorough set of resources. I actually do have BBH and I can do some basic paradigms and parsing etc. But I don't want to go any further with grammar because I find that learning grammar is unhelpful for language acquisition (despite the fact that I'm an amateur linguist). For this reason, I'm very specifically requesting direct-method material (i.e. People teaching the language using only the language).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for Biblical Hebrew, you might try Aleph with Beth.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. This is an excellent resource and exactly what I had in mind. I struggled to find it though, so if you link to it in the answer I will upvote and accept.

Comment: @LordRatte I don't know why it was downvoted but it is a poor answer because it does not describe what sort of resource 'Aleph with Beth' is.